# How can i change a material/color to an object from the main menu settings scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The title is pretty self explanatory. I have in the main menu scene a settings tab and in there i want to add a toggle that when enabled it changes the color or material from an object in a different scene. I did add the toggle but i have no idea what i should write in the script attached to it and how the script is going to be global. If somebody could help me please answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object persist through scenes loading/unloading with the [`DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) method, and have that object have a script which contains your Material information.

Simply:

1. Make a new script with a Material variable (or an integer, anything to signify the value)
2. In the `Start`, `Awake`, `OnEnable`, etc, use `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);`
3. Add the script to an object in your Main Menu scene

You can then use that variable in the new persistent GameObject's script to change the material.

Example implementation:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class GlobalSettings {

    //instance, so we can get this object statically
    public static GlobalSettings instance;

    [SerializeField] private Material[] choosableMaterials;
    private int materialIndex;

    //Property to return the current material
    public Material CurrentMaterial => choosableMaterials[materialIndex];

    //Set our instance variable
    public void OnEnable() {
        instance = this;
    }

    //OnClick method for your button. Implement however you're changing the materials.
    public void MaterialButtonPress(int value) {
        materialIndex = value;
    }
}
```

and in the scripts that you want to be able to access this value...

```cs
//start of class...

    public void Start() {
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>(); //change to whatever renderer type you're using
        renderer.material = GlobalSettings.instance.CurrentMaterial;
    }

//rest of class...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar thing in my game where I let players choose wrestler's mask's color. You can change texture of material by using Material.mainTexture.
check out the docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTexture.html)
You can also change color using Material.color. [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-color.html#:%7E:text=The%20main%20color%20of%20the,to%20be%20the%20main%20color)

Good luck